# 1D CNN time series classiifcation : ValueError: Shapes (10, 10, 8) and (10, 8) are incompatible

Tags: keras, time-series, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I'm working on a time series classification using ASHRAE RP-1043 chiller dataset which has 65 columns and more than 3000 rows for each chiller fault and normal condition. And I have used 1D CNN and training results are 99.35% which is pretty good and tested with data that didn't involve in training data set. and my output categorical feature is one hot encoded
[image: ![chiller dataset]
Following is the code i used for it and works pretty good.And the train data shape is as following

```
# make it 3d  input 
X_train = scaled_x_train.reshape(-1,1,65)
X_train.shape,y_train.shape`
```

> ((81600, 1, 65), (81600, 8))

```
  def create_nn_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = create_nn_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,batch_size=10,verbose=1)
```

But here when i change the kernel size to 3 and max pooling size to 2 and also the input shape as in the following i get the following error.

```
# make it multi steps compatible input 
X_train = scaled_x_train.reshape(-1,10,65)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,10,8)
X_train.shape,y_train.shape

>((8160, 10, 65), (8160, 10, 8))

def create_nn_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = create_nn_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,batch_size=10,verbose=1)
```

> ValueError: Shapes (10, 10, 8) and (10, 8) are incompatible.

```
Model: "sequential_81"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_141 (Conv1D)          (None, 8, 64)             12544     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_142 (Conv1D)          (None, 6, 64)             12352     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_61 (Dropout)         (None, 6, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_61 (MaxPooling (None, 3, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_58 (Flatten)         (None, 192)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_91 (ModuleWra (None, 8)                 1544      
=================================================================
Total params: 26,440
Trainable params: 26,440
Non-trainable params: 0
```

May be i may not have very much clear idea as to what kernel and filters. Or is it something to be done with the my 3d input shape? Can please anyone advice me on setting up the structure of data for the model's input layer (both X and Y)

Comment: @Kaveh Hi sorry i was trying many configurations and error message was fixed now. I have devided both my x and y to use 10 time steps since i want to use more than one kernel size in convolutional layer. The second dimension you asked for is time step. It should be 10.

Comment: (8160,10,65) this is the shape of the input data(X_train) but i have to reshape y_train also to shape as (8160,10,8) otherwise i will get error message when fitting the model saying both x and y arrays should be in same size. So I had to reshape the y_train also. and also i have one hot encoded my y (y_train & y_test) my categorical output variable. Can you please suggest me how to avoid this error. In LSTM there is a option called return_sequences set to true but here there is not

Comment: @Kaveh Can you please direct me with an example based on the code here? as to how can i adopt a timedistributed wrapper?

Comment: I couldn't find an example where TimeDistributed layer has been used in Conv1D other than in Conv2D

Comment: Wrap the CNN layer with TimeDistributed [_See here_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633490/2187625).

Comment: @Kaveh X_train got the shape of (81600, 65) and y_train (81600,8). So to input this train data i reshape X_train to (8160,10,65) to devide into 10 time steps. But still the Y_train is shape of (81600,8) the sizes are different. If I reshape the y_train to have the same batch size as X_train with the shape of (8160,10,8). Then Y_pred and Y true are different and this issue comes

Comment: @Kaveh Hi, 81600 is before reshaping. once reshaped by 10 time steps, batch size becomes 8160 not 81600. Before reshaing both X_train and y_train has 81600 batch size. Hope you get my problem properly ;)

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks a lot for your information. I also think that I'm confused about the input data shape. Can you please tell me to achieve a scenario where you send 10 records in the data set i have posted a picture of to a predict function of a model and considering all the 10 input samples (since its is a portion of a sequential data) can i get a one possible class label classified? if yes what should be the best Conv1D or LSTM? and always the timestep should be set to 1 to achieve that?

Comment: @Kaveh Will you please be able to point out how can i change my data structure as it is fitting to the model? I have excel file with each records labeled with relevant condition. and there are 7 excel files for 7 different different chiller conditions. I have appended all these 7 files records labeled into a data frame as in the picture i have posted.

Comment: to be more clear IRIS data set can be considered as a example for the data set structure i have used

Comment: Each file has 5190 records and all these 5190 records should have a one class labeled as per the condition.

Comment: @Kaveh if you can give your answer i can mark it ;)